# Sanity.io & react-query: Chain deleting documents with references

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, sanity, tanstackreact-query

I have a situation where I want to archive a number of documents inside a document, then delete them, and then delete a document to which the documents were referenced to, and I get the usual delete error where Sanity tells me the document has references(even tho they just have been deleted). If I delete the document again after, it works. It is like my code is not waiting for the initial deletion. Any help would be appreciated

I have a document named `register` that has a collection of `devices` and a collection of `nonConformites` that reference to a `device` and to the `register`.

I have a `archivedDevices` array inside the register. I create a `register` doc that has the device and non conformities that I want to archive inside. I take a way all the references, keeping only the data I need to archive.

```
const deviceDoc = {
 ...device,
archivedNonConformities: [...nonConformitiesToArchive] 
}

const registerDoc = {
...register,
archivedDevices: [deviceDoc]
}
```

At first I update the `register` document using CreateRelace, where I add the `registerDoc`.
in the code I also add any existing archived devices, all without any references.

using react-query, on success is now time to delete the orniginal nonConformities (that have the reference to the device). Once this is successful, is now time to finally delete the device, and here I get the error.

here is the delete documents function that I use to delete the nonConformities

```
const deleteDocuments = async (documents=[]) => {
  
        const queue = new PromiseQueue({
          concurrency: 11,
          intervalCap: 15,
          interval: 900,
        })
        let completedArray = []
        documents.forEach((item) => {

            queue.add(() => {
      
            return deleteDocument({documentId: item?._id},{
                onSuccess:()=>{
                    console.log("=====success deleted document====")
                    completedArray?.push(true)
                },
                onError:(err)=>{
                    console.log("===== error deleted document ====", err?.message, item?._id)
                    completedArray?.push(false)
                }
            })
          })
        })
        if(completedArray?.length == documents?.length && completedArray.every((x=>x==true)) ) return true
        return false
  
}
```

and this is the code i run onSuccess of the register update that should do the deletion.

```
        onSuccess:()=>{
            console.log("=====success updated register====")

            new Promise((myResolve, myReject) => {

                    const result =  deleteDocuments(nonConformities)
                    if(result) myResolve(console.log("_____resolved_____")); 

                }).then(()=>{
                    console.log("_____deleting device_____")
                    deleteDocuments([device]);
                })
            }
```

it should delete the device after the non conformities are deleted, instead it still finds the deleted references. If there are no nonConformities, the device is deleted with no problem, which of course is what happens if I run it a second time.

Maybe it is something simple, but I am really stuck. Thank you for your help!